# Twitter Bootstrap : logo on top of navbar ?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using twitter bootstrap and really enjoy it as im not used to do webpages. Have a question though, i have a round logo and i would like to place it on top of a navbar - like shown on the image.

I can add an image inside the navbar, but as shown here i somehow want to put it on top of the navbar where as the logo will be larger than the navbar and look like on the picture.

Basically i would like to have a large circle (the logo) where the navbar will go through it in the middle with the logo on top.

can this be done ? thanks

edit : cant post pictures :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say what you want exactly without having the image, but here is a guess:
Add the logo inside the block of your navbar and then, to your CSS file, set your image to have `position: absolute` and adjust the position by using, for instance, `left` and `top`.